# How can i sort Generic list with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, sorting, generic-list

How can i sort  myScriptCellsCount.MyCellsCharactersCount (list int type) in linq

```
    public class MyExcelSheetsCells
    {
        public List<int> MyCellsCharactersCount { get; set; }

        public MyExcelSheetsCells()
        {
            MyCellsCharactersCount = new List<int>();
        }

    }
```

```
   void ArrangedDataList(DataTable dTable)
        {
            DAL.MyExcelSheets myexcelSheet = new DAL.MyExcelSheets();
            myScriptCellsCount = new TestExceltoSql.DAL.MyExcelSheetsCells();

            foreach (DataColumn col in dTable.Columns)
                myexcelSheet.MyColumnNames.Add(col.ColumnName.ToString());
            foreach(DataColumn dc in dTable.Columns)
            foreach (DataRow  dr in dTable.Rows)
                myScriptCellsCount.MyCellsCharactersCount.Add(dr[dc].ToString().Length);
          //How can i sort desc
            //myScriptCellsCount.MyCellsCharactersCount = from list in myScriptCellsCount.MyCellsCharactersCount
            //                                            orderby list.CompareTo( descending
            //                                            select list;
            CreatSqlTable(myexcelSheet.MyColumnNames, dTable.TableName, myScriptCellsCount.MyCellsCharactersCount[0].ToString());
            myscript.WriteScript(myscript.SqlScripts);
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

```
// using Linq
MyCellsCharactersCount.OrderBy(x => x);            // ascending
MyCellsCharactersCount.OrderByDescending(x => x);  // descending
```

or

```
// not using Linq
MyCellsCharactersCount.Sort();                     // ascending
MyCellsCharactersCount.Sort().Reverse();           // descending
```

Comment: It should be OrderByDescending.

Answer (score 9):

You can use OrderBy or Sort, but there is a difference between the 2 that you should understand:

If you do sort, it sorts your list "in place", so in this example, the variable "list" gets sorted:

```
// you can manipulate whether you return 1 or -1 to do ascending/descending sorts
list.Sort((x, y) =>
{
   if (x > y) return 1;
   else if (x == y) return 0;
   else return -1;
});
```

If you do an OrderBy, the original list is unaffected, but a new, sorted enumerable is returned:

```
var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(x => x)
```

**Edit**

This answer was recently upvoted, so I reviewed it.  In my original response, I left out a really important detail:

If you use the LINQ code above (second example), the sort is going to occur every time  you iterate over the variable "sorted".  So, if you have it in more than 1 foreach, you will repeat the sort.  To avoid that, change the code above to:

```
var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList(); // or .ToArray()
```

That will force the enumerator to run, and will store the result in sorted.

If you are only going to enumerate it once, you can leave out the ToList/ToArray call.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the OrderBy method on your list.

```
IEnumerable sortedList = myScriptCellsCount.MyCellsCharactersCount.OrderBy(anInt => anInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorted = from i in MyCellsCharacterCount orderby i descending select i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12920596/1139347). You can replace "Process" with your object by getting typeOf your List.

Cheers