# How to sort a list of objects by a specific member?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

Say I have a list of Person objects:

```
class person
{
  int id;
  string FirstName;
  string LastName;
}
```

How would I sort this list by the LastName member?

```
List<Person> myPeople = GetMyPeople();
myPeople.Sort(/* what goes here? */);
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062373/how-can-i-sort-generic-list-with-linq

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under C# 3.0 you can use the following linq statement:

```
var sortedEnumerable = myPeople.OrderBy( p => p.LastName );
```

Answer (score 17):

`List<T>.Sort` will sort the list in-place. If that's what you want, sweet: use [the overload that takes a `Comparison<T>` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
List<Person> myPeople = GetMyPeople();
myPeople.Sort((x, y) => x.LastName.CompareTo(y.LastName));
```

If you don't want to modify the actual list but want to enumerate over its contents in a sorted order, then, as others have suggested, use [the LINQ extension method `OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) (.NET 3.5 and up) instead. This method can take a simple `Func<T, TKey>` selector and order by the keys which this selector... you know, selects.

```
List<Person> myPeople = GetMyPeople();
var orderedByLastName = myPeople.OrderBy(p => p.LastName);
```

Comment: Best answer so far. Its annoying to create a IComparer for every Property you want to sort on.

Comment: There is also an OrderByDescending method in LINQ if that is the order you need.

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested, you can use a custom [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx) method to sort your list.  If you're only doing it once, the easiest way is using an anonymous method like such:

```
List<Person> myPeople = GetMyPeople();
myPeople.Sort(delegate(Person one, Person two)
{
    return one.LastName.CompareTo(two.LastName);
});
```

Alternatively, you can implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) on your Person class, so that the class knows how to sort itself:

```
class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    int id;
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;

    public int CompareTo(Person other)
    {
        return LastName.CompareTo(other.LastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to write a comparer:

```
class LastNameComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
   public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
   {
       return String.Compare(x.LastName, y.LastName);
   }
}
```

An then

```
myPeople.Sort(new LastNameComparer());
```

`Person` may also implement `IComparable<Person>`, in which case `myPeople.Sort()` will suffice. However, you may want to sort by other properties on other places, so this isn't a general method; if you want to sort by `ID` on another report you can write another `IComparer`, but you can only have one `IComparable<Person>.CompareTo(Person other)` method.

If you're feeling lazy, or sure you won't use it again, you can also use a lambda:

```
myPeople.Sort((p1, p2) => String.Compare(p1.LastName, p2.LastName));
```

Answer (score 1):

A custom `IComparer<person>`. If you are using c#3.0 and .net3.5, have a look into the LINQ Methods, espescially `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy()`.

Answer (score 1):

example of ICompare

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Sort class on LastName Descending Order
   /// </summary>
   private class PersonLastNameDescending : IComparer<Person>
   {
      public int Compare(Person aX, Person aY)
      {
         return aY.LastName.CompareTo(aX.LastName);
      } // end Compare(...)
   } // end inner class PersonLastNameDescending 

   MyPeople.Sort(new PersonLastNameDescending());
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing needs to go inside your "Sort" method call if your class implements `IComparable`.

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) for detail.

Code:

```
class person : IComparable<person>
{ 
  int id; 
  string FirstName; 
  string LastName; 

public int CompareTo(person other)
    {
        //If you want to sort on FirstName
        return FirstName.CompareTo(other.FirstName);
    }


}
```