# Help With Generic LINQ OrderBy Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by, expression

Trying to get an OrderBy on an IQueryable to work, not having much luck.

Here's my method:

```
public ICollection<T> FindAll<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T,int>> orderingKey) where T : Post
{
    return repository
             .Find()
             .Where(predicate)
             .OfType<T>()
             .OrderBy(orderingKey)
             .ToPagedList();
}
```

The ordering works if i do this:

```
FindAll(p => p.PostName == "Foo", p => p.PostId);
```

But not if i want to do this:

```
FindAll(p => p.PostName == "Foo", p => p.DateModified);
```

It doesn't work of course, because i have declared the Expression as `T,int`, whereas the above expression is of type `T,DateTime`

How do i declare it so i can OrderBy **any** property of my entity (Post)?

This is LINQ-Entities (Entity Framework 4.0).

Comment: Take a look at [this answer][1]

Cheers


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12920596/1139347

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`Queryable.OrderBy`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264.aspx) takes a key selector with the following type:

```
Expression<Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector>
```

If you change orderingKey to an expression of this type then it will work. You will also need to add another type parameter.

```
public ICollection<T> FindAll<T, TKey>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderingKey
) where T : Post
```

Comment: so a) what do i change my method declaration to, and b) how do i change the usage?

Comment: @RPM1984: You don't have to change the usage.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to at least have a generic parameter type defined for the ordering key.  Instead of returning int, return a generic type.

e.g.,

```
public ICollection<TPost> FindAll<TPost,TOrder>(Expression<Func<TPost,bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<TPost,TOrder>> orderingKey) where TPost : Post
{
    return repository
             .Find()
             .Where(predicate)
             .OfType<TPost>()
             .OrderBy(orderingKey)
             .ToPagedList();
}
```