# c# generic orderby

Tags: linq, entity-framework, generics, sql-order-by, expression

In my base-repository class

i wrote this function to make possible to retrive a sorted data collection from the DB.
T is a generic defined at Class level

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> 
        where T : class
```

The code is this:

```
public IList<T> GetAll<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereCondition, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> sortCondition, bool sortDesc = false)
        {
            if (sortDesc)
                return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).OrderByDescending(sortCondition).ToList<T>();

            return this.ObjectSet.Where(whereCondition).OrderBy(sortCondition).ToList<T>() ;
        }
```

My goal was to introduce a *generic* sort parameter so that i could call the function in this way:

```
repo.GetAll (model=>model.field>0, model=>model.sortableField, true)
```

i mean that i could specify the sorting field directly via anonymous function and so using Intellisense...

Unfortunately this function doesn't work as the last code line generate errors at compile time.

I tried also to call:

```
repo.GetAll<Model> (model=>model.field>0, model=>model.sortableField, true)
```

but this don't work.

How should i write the function to meet my goal?

i'm working with EF 5, c#, .NET 4.5

Comment: And the compile-time error is...? (*Any* time you have an error, whether compile-time or execution-time, please include it in the question. Don't keep us guessing.)

Comment: I think it should be Func<...> not Expression<Func<...>>

Comment: I was totally screwed. My function was working good, but i called it with a wrong Where condition... 
Should i delete this question?

Anyway @EliAlgranti , i copied the template of the where condition parameters from a .NET tutorial. Can you tell me the difference between  Func<...> and Expression<Func<...>> and why Func<...> should work better?

Comment: Also, here i've just found a similar question, and here too they use Expression<Func<...>>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828591/help-with-generic-linq-orderby-lambda-expression?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `ObjectSet` which implements `IQueryable<T>`.  That is extended by methods on `System.Linq.Queryable`, which accept `Expression<Func<` parameters.  It is correct to use those `Expression` parameters, as you intend for execution to occur in the database, not locally.

- A Func is an anonymous delegate, a .net method.
- An Expression is a tree, which may be compiled into a Func, or may be translated into Sql or something else.

---

You showed us a really abstract use of the method, but not an actual use of the method, or the compiler error.  I suspect the error you may be making is confusing the two type parameters.

You said:

```
repo.GetAll<Model> (model=>model.field>0, model=>model.sortableField, true)
```

But this generic parameter for this method represents the type of sortableField.  If sortableField isn't a Model - this is wrong.

Instead, you should be doing something like this:

```
Repository<Person> myRepo = new Repository<Person>();
myRepo.GetAll<DateTime>(p => p.Friends.Count() > 3, p => p.DateOfBirth, true);
```

If specifying the sort type breaks your intended pattern of usage, consider hiding that key by using an IOrderer: [Store multi-type OrderBy expression as a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737355/store-multi-type-orderby-expression-as-a-property/7742446#7742446)

Comment: Thanks much for the reply. In my last comments i just said that the code i wrote in the question seems to work good. The error was generated by the 'where condition'. Pratically model.field>0 was failin because field was a String...
Anyway i thank you very much as you solved me another couple doubts... I will mark your as the accepted answer because it explain very well the Expression concept.